# Accessing phpMyAdmin (Xampp) from another network

Tags: vb.net, windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

Okay. I have no problem accessing phpMyadmin on my local network but is it possible to access it from another network? If possible, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to create a VPN, or enable port forwarding on your router.

http://m.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2030763/how-and-why-to-set-up-a-vpn-today.html